# Computer Engine show normal, but all ports are unavailable

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Why does the instance in my Computer Engine show normal, but all ports are unavailable, and a few hours ago, all functions were normal

A few days ago, my instance was attacked. Google sent me an email telling me that my instance was conducting mining activities and the resources were suspended. After I appealed, I deleted the instance and then recreated it. Now every time I create an instance , The instance can only be used for a few hours, then all the ports of the instance are unavailable, and the IP cannot be pinged

If someone could tell me what to do, I would really appreciate him

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you contact GCP support for this; they will be able to investigate your issue internally and tell you specifically the cause of the issue and the next steps for resolution.

https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Comment: "Talk to Support" would make a great comment on the question, but is not an answer.